# Problem creating a service on Debian

Tags: debian, systemd, services

I have a Sinatra application at /my/app/folder/app.rb which I normally execute on my local machine with the command `rackup -p 9210`. I would like to create a service that starts the app at every boot and restart. I have tried the following but it did not work:

```
$ vim /lib/systemd/system/mydaemon.service

[Unit]
Description=Simple supervisor

[Service]
User=username
Group=username
WorkingDirectory=/my/app/folder/
Restart=always
ExecStart=/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/bin/rackup -p 9210
```

Then I reload the deamons:
`systemctl- deamon-reload`, start the service: `systemctl start mydaemon` and check status and  I get this error:

```
● mydeamon.service - Simple deamon
   Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/mydeamon.service; static)
   Active: failed (Result: start-limit) since Wed 2017-12-06 17:07:39 GMT; 5s ago
  Process: 355 ExecStart=/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/bin/rackup -p 9210 (code=exited, status=127)
 Main PID: 355 (code=exited, status=127)

mydeamon.service: main process exited, code=exited, status=127/n/a
Unit mydeamon.service entered failed state.
mydeamon.service holdoff time over, scheduling restart.
Stopping Simple deamon...
Starting Simple deamon...
mydeamon.service start request repeated too quickly, refusing to start.
Failed to start Simple deamon.
Unit mydeamon.service entered failed state.
```

What am I missing here?

I use RVM so I have also tried:

`ExecStart=/usr/local/rvm/wrappers/ruby-2.3.0/rackup -p 9210`

but it didn't work either.
I would appreciate any suggestions.

Comment: I think status 127 is "not executable", due to can't find the path or not allowed to execute it. Did you try running the command specified in ExecStart manually?

Comment: Also a side note: you should add services to /etc/systemd/system/, not /lib/systemd/system/.

Comment: And you're missing a "WantedBy", although to be honest I'm not 100% certain it's required. Docs here: https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.service.html